Scripting Python - Identify which textures of material are used as normal map, diffuse etc. PBR workflow
I'm writing a python script to import an asset, and doing some extractions of tree structure, materials data to save in cloud DB. In this process, while extracting metadata of materials, I'm able to retrieve all the textures(images) attached to a material. I want to figure out which one of these textures is applied as a diffuse map, which is used for normals, displacement etc.
Obviously, I can't use the image names - say "Car_Diffuse", as this may vary. so i think some property of shader nodes or something I can check to verify the same?
I went through docs and a lot of forums, still looking to find a solution.

Not a full answer, but the open source code in Blender's glTF exporter might be helpful. It searches for textures attached to particular sockets on the Principled BSDF node: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/main/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/material/pbr_metallic_roughness.py
